# Php error with library Mike 42

Tags: php, printing

I already have a lot of time working with php, but I came across a project related to the printing of tickets and the truth there are not many librarys related to that and the one I found that is called mike 42 is giving me many problems with the example that is in The library and then continue with the application.And the problem is that there is not much documentation related to the errors that can be caused.

The error message I encounter is:

> Warning: copy(\Luis_Enrique\EPSON TM-T20 Receipt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\Probar_Ticket\src\Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector.php on line 372

Here is my code:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\CupsPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;


// Enter the device file for your USB printer here
try {
    /* add to the printer */
    $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("EPSON TM-T20 Receipt");

    $printer = new Printer($connector);
    /* write */
    $printer->text("Hola Mundo!\n");
    /* Cut tiket */
    $printer->cut();
    /* Close printer */
    $printer->close();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Couldn't print to this printer: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

The error is not if it is in the code, in the wampserver that requires a specific permission or in which it is tried that the printer is not comparable with the library, and also in my opinion the library lacks much of the documentation. Or do not know if they know of some other library.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your problem is that when you instantiate the `WindowsPrintConnector`, you need to pass in the name of the printer with which it is shared:

```
$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("EPSON TM-T20 Receipt");
```

Apparently, it isn't available under that name.

Try the troubleshooting at https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/blob/development/example/interface/windows-usb.php#L13-L18.