# copy(\\DESKTOP-O2ERE3M\EPSON TM-T82 Receipt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory ESC POS

Tags: php, laravel

Hello to those who are using mike42/escpos and Laravel. When I test first on my local computer it works fine, it would print. But when I deploy it on the server, it would produce an error copy(\DESKTOP-O2ERE3M\EPSON TM-T82 Receipt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.  For instance, after I deploy my project in the windows server, which I would access now my project through the internet, I was not able to print from my printer which connected to my computer and thus it produces an error that I mentioned above The printer is already a shared one. For short I'm trying to print the receipt using my printer installed in my computer from the server through the internet. I'm using a Laravel framework

```
$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("EPSON TM-T82 Receipt"); 
$printer = new Printer($connector); 
$printer -> text("Hello World\n"); 
$printer -> cut(); 
$printer -> close();
```

I'm also using XAMPP on my server.

Comment: I'm using the Windows server. I'm using a virtual box and the name of it DESKTOP-O2ERE3M. I already shared my printer on my computer and I saw that my printer is redirected on the server but I can't able to share my printer on server

Comment: Hey @jec360, This questions has already answered here ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380755/php-error-with-library-mike-42?rq=1

Comment: I tried that answer sir

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Php error with library Mike 42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380755/php-error-with-library-mike-42)

Comment: No sir. For instance after I deploy my project in the windows server, which I would access now my project through the internet, I was not able to print from my printer which connected to my computer and thus it produce an error that I mention above

Comment: Obviously ...there is no printer called "EPSON TM-T82 Receipt" on that server.

Comment: So I'm finding a way that after I deploy on the server, I would able to print the receipt to the thermal printer because I think that code would only be effective in my localhost in my computer

Answer (score 0):

Include the library

Composer

This library is designed for use with the composer PHP dependency manager. Simply add the mike42/escpos-php package to get started:

```
composer require mike42/escpos-php
```

If you haven't used composer before, you can read about it at getcomposer.org.

Requirements

This project has few hard dependencies:

```
PHP 7.0 or newer.
json extension, used to load bundled printer definitions (see documentation)
intl extension, used for character encoding (see documentation)
zlib extension, used for de-compressing bundled resources (see documentation).
It is also suggested that you install either imagick or gd, as these can be used to 
speed up image processing.
```

A number of optional extensions can be added to enable more specific features. These are described in the "suggest" section of composer.json.

The 'Hello World' receipt
To make use of this driver, your server (where PHP is installed) must be able to communicate with your printer. Start by generating a simple receipt and sending it to your printer using the command-line.

```
<?php
/* Call this file 'hello-world.php' */
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
$connector = new FilePrintConnector("php://stdout");
$printer = new Printer($connector);
$printer -> text("Hello World!\n");
$printer -> cut();
$printer -> close();
```

Some examples are below for common interfaces.

Communicate with a printer with an Ethernet interface using netcat:

```
php hello-world.php | nc 10.x.x.x. 9100
```

Comment: Yes sir I installed composer in my project. But still it has an error